# Game development questions about UI

Tags: discussion, user-interface

Hey guys, over at [StackExchange User Interface](http://ui.stackexchange.com) we're fielding questions about UI and I thought it might be nice to mention it over here, as we haven't really had any UI questions pertaining to game development. It made me wonder if you guys are currently answering those here, and whether you think it'd be useful for the game dev community to be made aware of the UI community. If so, we might be able to get Robert/Jeff to cross-promote UI on gamedev or something eventually.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 2):

I think the overlap between this and UI is going to be similar to this and stackoverflow itself w.r.t. programming questions. Namely, it's about the audience that reads this site more so than the content it covers.

That being said, there haven't been a lot of UI-specific questions here.

Answer (score 2):

I think questions that deal with UI architecture (e.g. UI frameworks/subsystems) as they pertain to game development should be answered here.  General UX questions, especially those concerning UX *design*, should probably be fielded to the UI StackExchange.  Naturally, there may be some overlap, as there may be some design questions which are specific to games.  All we can really do is judge these on a case-by-case basis.  Personally, I'm fine if people ask UX design questions here, as long as they pertain to games.  However, if I feel the poster may get more useful feedback from the UI StackExchange, I will certainly let them know.